# How to pass attributes in Laravel scope using name argument (PHP8 feature)

Tags: laravel, eloquent, php-8.2, laravel-scopes

In my `Setting` model. I have a local `scope` that accepts `$data` array argument. The `$data` contains two keys `group` and `property` and any of them can be null as you can see in my query.

```
 public function scopeSettingFilters($query, array $data)
    {
        $query->when(!empty($data['group']), fn($q) => $q->where("group", $data["group"]));

        $query->when(!empty($data['property']), function ($q) use ($data) {
            $property = $data['property'];

            if (str_contains($property, '.')) {
                [$group, $property] = $this->splitKey($data['property']);
                $q->where(["group" => $group, "name" => $property]);

            } else {
                $q->where("name", $property);
            }
        });

        return $query;
    }
```

Now I want to convert `$data` array keys to [Named Arguments](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#128022) for better code understanding and one major reason for conversion is, that currently the `group` is accepting only `string` but now it is either a `string` or `array`.

##### My Setting Table

| id | user_id | group | property | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | notifications | event_email | true |
| 1 | 1 | onboarding | welcome_video_watched | false |

> **Note:** I'm using `Laravel 9`  Version

##### Expected Syntax:

After making the required changes I would able to call `Laravel query scope` using `named argument` something like that:

```
Setting::settingFilters(group: "onboarding")->get()    //filter single group

Setting::settingFilters(group: ["onboarding", "notifications"])->get()    //filter multiple groups
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to refactor your code to use named arguments, you can change the function signature of scopeSettingFilters to accept named arguments instead of a single $data array. You can set default values for the arguments to null to make them optional.

Here's an example that shows how you could refactor your code:

```
public function scopeSettingFilters($query, string|array|null $group = null, string|null $property = null)
{
    // Filter by 'group'
    $query->when(!empty($group), function ($q) use ($group) {
        if (is_array($group)) {
            $q->whereIn('group', $group);
        } else {
            $q->where('group', $group);
        }
    });

    // Filter by 'property'
    $query->when(!empty($property), function ($q) use ($property) {
        if (str_contains($property, '.')) {
            [$group, $property] = $this->splitKey($property);
            $q->where(['group' => $group, 'name' => $property]);
        } else {
            $q->where('name', $property);
        }
    });

    return $query;
}
```

Key changes:

The function now accepts named arguments $group and $property, both of which have default values set to null.

Inside the lambda function for the when() method, I've added a check for $group being an array. If it is an array, it uses whereIn to filter by multiple group names; otherwise, it uses where as you did before.

Now you can call this scope with named arguments like so:

```
// With a single group name
$query->settingFilters(group: 'someGroup');

// With multiple group names
$query->settingFilters(group: ['group1', 'group2']);

// With a property
$query->settingFilters(property: 'someProperty');

// With both a group and a property
$query->settingFilters(group: 'someGroup', property: 'someProperty');
```

Answer (score 0):

I had fixed it using following code:

```
 public function settingFilters(string|array $group = null, string $property = null)
    {
        $query = $this->settings();

        $group = is_array($group) ? $group : [$group];


        $query->when(!empty($group), fn($q) => $q->whereIn("group", $group));

        $query->when(!empty($data['property']), function ($q) use ($property) {

            if (str_contains($property, '.')) {
                [$group, $property] = $this->splitKey($property);
                $q->where(["group" => $group, "name" => $property]);

            } else {
                $q->where("name", $property);
            }
        });

        return $query;
    }
```